# How to change the array text being displayed?

Tags: php, arrays

Okay, I just want to print the contents of an array then I want to replace the the contents of the string of the array then replace the them with another name...plase someone help me...
I don't really get what to do to it, can someone show me how to do this right and how to use preg_replace? Everywhere I look up how to do it they have really weird symbols in it:

Even in my code, I just sorta put those things in it because its what everyone else does >.> even on the php manual website...I think I hate PHP

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>test6</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Insert your content here -->
<?php
class myArrayContainer{
    function myArrayFunction(){
        return $myArray = array(
            "Name" => "John",
            "LastName" => "Smith",
        );
    }

}
$myShitz = new myArrayContainer();
$myShit = $myShitz->myArrayFunction();
$myShitClass = new myArrayClass($myShit);


//print_r($myShit);
class myArrayClass {



    function __construct($myArray){

        echo ("Printing my Array as Recieved");
        echo ("</br>");
        print_r(array_values($myArray));

       $myProcessClass = new myProcess($myArray);
    }

}

class myProcess {
    function __construct($sameArray){
        $mySentence = serialize($sameArray);
        print_r($mySentence);
        $placements = array ("John" => "Jose", "Smith" => "Tobar");
        preg_replace("/:(\w+)/e", $placements[$1], $mySentence);
    }

}
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `print_r` in `myArrayClass::__construct` should print "John" and "Smith" (no keys). Doesn't it?
2. `$mySentence` is a string, so no `print_r` needed.
3. You're not doing anything with the `preg_replace` result...
4. You can't go change serialized data. PHP's serialized data is weird (not like JSON), so you can't go around changing values. If you want to change values, use `json_encode() -> preg_replace() -> json_decode()`:

.

```
$mySentence = json_encode($sameArray); // assoc array in
$mySentence = preg_replace('/a/', 'b', $mySentence);
$otherArray = json_decode($mySentence, true); // assoc array out
```

Be careful though. Even json can be messed up if you replace it like that.

Comment: when I run myArrayClass::__construct it prints this:

Array ( [0] => John [1] => Smith ) and when I added this:
$mySentence = json_encode($sameArray);

it also output this:

{"Name":"John","LastName":"Smith"}

Comment: $mySentence = json_encode($sameArray);
            $mySentence = preg_replace('/o/','t',$mySentence);
            $otherArray = json_decode($mySentence);
            print($otherArray);

I added that to my code but now it causes an error o.O what is JSON?

Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\Sites\test6.php on line 45

That's the error it gave me. 

Thanks for helping btw.

Comment: See: http://3v4l.org/gRlvt `json_decode()` creates objects by default, instead of associative arrays (like yours). You can make it create assoc arrays using the `$assoc` argument. [See docs.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: class myProcess {
        function __construct($sameArray){
            $mySentence = json_encode($sameArray);
            $mySentence = preg_replace('/o/','t',$mySentence);
            $otherArray = json_decode($mySentence);//this is line 45
            print($otherArray);
            //print($mySentence);
            //$placements = array ("John" => "Jose", "Smith" => "Tobar");
           // preg_replace("/:(\w+)/e", $placements[$1], $mySentence);
        }
        
    }

Comment: that's the part that causes problems

Comment: How do you use that argument? Sorry I'm kinda new to PHP :/

Comment: I've updated my answer, but if you couldn't find that, you don't know enough PHP to do anything.